# Error when using JSON JavaScriptSerializer "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property"

Tags: c#, json

I am using JavascriptSerializer within my C# code and I am getting an error that string value exceesa maxJSonLength. My object is filled from the database datatable that returns more than 50K rows. I tried changing maxJsonLength property in my App.Config file but the error does not go away. Please help

```
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000000"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Just in case, here is my C# code:

```
List<MyRecord> lst= ...;
string strJSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);
```

Comment: 50k rows seem to be too much for the client to handle. I recommend you apply some paging for better performance and lower bandwidthd :D.

Comment: how can I do that? could you give me some examples?

Comment: var page = 1;
var itemPerPage = 500;
List<MyRecord> pagedLst = lst.Skip(page).Take(itemPerPage).ToList();
string json = new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(pagedLst);

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxJsonLength` property is of type `int`, so its value cannot exceed `Int32.MaxValue`, which is 2147483644.